# Swift 3.0 Converting String to Date

Tags: swift, date, timezone

I'm trying to convert String date to local timeZone date then convert it back to Date with my current timeZone first method is working well:

```
  let date  =  convertToLocalTimeZone(dateStr:"2018-05-30T14:13:20.000Z")
        print(date)

    the following is printed which is right:
    2018-05-30 16:13GMT+2

let newDate = convertStringToDate(dateStr:date)

    print(newDate)

//Converted back to UTC Time Zone :(
2018-05-30 14:13:00 +0000



func convertToLocalTimeZone(dateStr:String)->String{
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sss.SSSZ"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        let date = dateFormatter.date (from: dateStr)
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: getSecondsFromGMT())
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmz"
        let strVal  = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
        return strVal

    }
```

The problem happens when i try to convert the new String date with my local timeZone to date it returns wrong timeZone:

```
func convertStringToDate(dateStr:String)->Date{
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat =  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmz"
// dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+2")
        let date = dateFormatter.date (from: dateStr)
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour], from: date!)
        let finalDate = calendar.date(from:components)
        return finalDate!
    }
```

Any Help will be much appreciated

Comment: `Date` doesn't have a timezone. Your code is fine. The output you are getting is fine. When you use `print` on a `Date`, it is always shown in UTC time. See http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html

Comment: Date objects have no concept of timezones. they are just point in times. if you print them directly they will always show UTC.

Comment: But i'm already passing it new date with 2 hours added according to my timezone why it is converted back to UTC

Comment: No, you are parsing strings that represent the same moment in time. Again, your code is fine. The output is fine. The only issue is your misunderstanding of what happens when you print a `Date` instance.

Comment: `2018-05-30T14:13:20.000Z` is May 30, 2018 at 14:13 GMT time. `2018-05-30 16:13GMT+2` is May 30 at 16:13 GMT+2 which is the exact same moment as 14:13 GMT. So they are the same moment simply shown in two different timezones.  `2018-05-30 14:13:00 +0000` is May 30 at 14:13 GMT. Again, the same time. It's all good. `+0000` and `Z` both mean the GMT+0 timezone.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but  i did find solution by adding seconds from GMT to my new date the problem was to compare 2 dates i didn't clear that it solved.

Comment: If you think you need to add seconds from GMT then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Why is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is alright. You just have to understand that `Date` represents a point in time. It does not know anything about time zones. Time zones appears only when you format the date, so only in a `String` will you ever see a time zone. No matter how you create a `Date`, you are going to see it end up in UTC when it is printed directly.

So if you want to show a date in a time zone, format it, just like you did in `convertToLocalTimeZone`.

If you want, you could create your own date with a `Date` and a `TimeZone`:

```
struct ZonedDate: CustomStringConvertible {
    var date: Date
    var timeZone: TimeZone

    var description: String {
        // format the date using timeZone here...
    }
}
```